# How to limit memory usage in MPICH2

Tags: mpi, mpich

For MPICH2, how to control the size of memory  to use of each node? Or, it is impossible to control it, it will use as much as it can?

I am measuring the different performances of the program under different resource configuration, for example, you can limit the max cores number through the parameter of `mpiexec`: `cores`. But I have no idea that how to limit the memory, so I want to know is there any way to limit the size of the memory when you use MPICH.

Comment: This is too broad of a question. Please narrow it down to a specific issue and possibly accompany it with code samples.

Comment: i am measuring the different performance of program under different resource configuration,for example ,you can limit the max cores number through the parameter of mpiexec: cores .But,i have no idea that how to limit the memory ,so I want to know is there any way to limit the size of the memory when you use MPICH2?thank you for your time

Comment: Take that comment response as a hint to edit your question. In the review stack it is very easy to mark this as too broad or that it is open to too many personal opinions. If you can list supporting arguments or metrics or describe the scenario where you are concerned about memory use, then we will be more eager to help.

Comment: By limiting the memory you potentially want to rely on swapping. In HPC community, where MPICH2 comes from, performance is key and swapping is really against the goals. So they avoid it and I am not surprised if they don't provide a way to limit the memory usage.

Comment: In HPC environments when you can reserve a node partially (not a very good thing) it is usually the queue system that will just kill the program if it uses more RAM than it requested.

Comment: Please have a look how I edited your question. Learn to use commas, full stops and question-marks properly. There is no space before them and a space after them. It will help you everywhere you write something, not just at this website but everywhere in your practical life. Also "I" is spelled capital.